# Pre activation resnet18 is slower than resnet18 for no reason

Tags: pytorch, classification, resnet

I've got a question while training resnet18 and pre-activation resnet18

Those colab notebooks are simple implementations of training time comparision between resnet18 and pre-activation resnet18 by training only 1 epochs

https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1QGDKVtXX0FufZ5QnfBuKNE5_L8La8sNk?usp=sharing

As you can see from output, pre-activation resnet18 takes two time as long to learn resnet18

```
ResNet18 trainig time: 23.68 seocond
PreActResNet18 training time: 43.50 seocond
```

I don't understand why preactresnet18 is much slower than resnet because as you can see from model summary, both have approximately the same number of parameters and I didn't find anything that would slow it down by a factor of two.

Thanks

resnet18

```
================================================================
Total params: 11,506,122
Trainable params: 11,506,122
Non-trainable params: 0
```

pre activation resnet18

```
================================================================
Total params: 11,171,146
Trainable params: 11,171,146
Non-trainable params: 0
```

Comment: You can use pytorch lightning profiler to investigate it: https://pytorch-lightning.readthedocs.io/en/1.5.10/advanced/profiler.html